# How to show right border of textarea element

Tags: html, css

I have code below. I have 2 questions:

1. Why right border of `textarea` is hidden? How to show it not use padding for `div` child1?
2. I don't set `height` for `div` child1. Why child1 is higher than `textarea`? How to fit it with `textarea`?

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent' style='width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: blue; position: absolute;'>
  <div id='child1' style='background-color: red; margin: 10px; overflow: hidden;'>
    <textarea style='width: 100%; height: 100px; resize: none; border: 2px solid black;'></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Solution 1: To fix the border issue Add: `box-sizing: border-box;`
Solution 2 : To fix the height issue: Add: `float: left;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the below CSS to `textarea` in your snippet to solve the two issues you have mentioned

**Solution 1: To fix the border issue**

`box-sizing: border-box;`

**Solution 2 : Float to fix the height issue**

`float: left;`

**Code Snippet:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div {
  background-color: red;
}
#child1 {
  width: 80%; 
}

textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Solution 1: To fix the border issue */
  float: left; /* Solution 2 : Float to fix the height issue */
}
```

```html
<div id='parent' style='width:  100%; height: 100%; background-color: blue; position: absolute;'>
  <div id='child1' style='background-color: red; margin: 10px; overflow: hidden;'>
    <textarea style='width: 100%; height: 100px; resize: none; border: 2px solid black;'></textarea>
    <div id="clear" style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id='parent' style='width: 100%;height:100%;background-color:blue;position:absolute;'>

    <div id='child1' style='background-color:red;margin:10px;overflow:hidden;'>
      <textarea style='width:-webkit-fill-available;height:100px;resize:none;border:2px solid black;overflow:hidden'></textarea>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

thats the solution!!
your Problem was, that the Red div was as big as the text-area,
but the border doesn't count to the width, or height of an element.
so `width:100%`actually results into """width:100% + 2px of the left Border and + 2px on the right Border""".
but `width:-webkit-fill-available` counts the boreder in, with the non-advantage, (at least i think it is), that it does not work in every Browser

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the overflow element in DIV tag. you have given **overflow: hidden;** With the hidden value, the overflow is clipped, The overflow property only works for block elements with a specified height.

```js
function within(){
    document.getElementById("child1").style.height = document.getElementById("textarea").offsetHeight + "px";
    console.log(document.getElementById("textarea").offsetHeight + "px it die höhe vom Text!")
    }
    
    function without(){
    document.getElementById("child1").style.height = "unset";
    
    
    }
```

```css
    * {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }

    div {
      background-color: red;
    }
    button {
    position:relative;}
```

```html
    <div id='parent' style='width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: blue; position: absolute;'>
      <div id='child1' style='background-color: red; margin: 10px;'>
        <textarea id="textarea" style='width: 100%; height: 100px; resize: none; border: 2px solid black;'></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="within()">mit Höhe</button>
    <button onclick="without()">ohne Höhe</button>
```

Comment: Please add some explaination what you changed?

Answer (score 0):

Removing `overflow: hidden` from your `div` will display `textarea` border.

```css
* {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}

div {
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent' style='width:  100%; height: 100%; background-color: blue; position: absolute;'>
  <div id='child1' style='background-color: red; margin: 10px;'>
    <textarea style='width: 100%; height: 100px; resize: none; border: 2px solid black;'></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `box-sizing:border-box`

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the answers to your questions:

1. You should use the CSS [`calc`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp) function to reduce the `textarea`'s 100%-`width` by 4px (which is the sum of the 2px border on the left and right sides);
2. You should apply [`float`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) to `left` for `textarea` to reduce `#child1`'s height.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div {
  background-color: red;
}

#parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}

#child1 {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

textarea {
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
  height: 100px;
  resize: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <div id='child1'>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Textarea has **display: inline-block;** styling by default so just change it to **display: block;**

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div {
  background-color: red;
}
textarea{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent' style='width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: blue; position: absolute;'>
  <div id='child1' style='background-color: red; margin: 10px; overflow: hidden;'>
    <textarea style='width: 100%; height: 100px; resize: none; border: 2px solid black;'></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```